# Components added to Page Design are not showing in page

Tags: sxa

When I add some component to page design and select that page design for a page, the components present in page design are not reflecting in page.

On the other hand, if I add components to a partial design, select them in page design, then the same is visible in page.

I am using sitecore 8.1 with SXA 1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page Designs are just for grouping Partial Designs. And Partial Designs are the place where you should be dropping renderings. Looks like you need to do your homework with reading some docs:

- [Page Designs](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/page_design/page_designs)
- Create and assign a page design - look [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/page_design/create_and_assign_a_page_design_in_the_content_editor) and [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/page_design/create_and_assign_a_page_design_in_the_experience_editor)
- [Create and change a partial design](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/designing/page_design/create_and_change_a_partial_design)

Besides the official documentation you might be interested in reading some blogs (**FIRST** hit on Google) too: [Partial and Page Designs in SXA](https://thecodeattic.wordpress.com/2018/05/08/partial-and-page-designs-in-sxa/)